# Calculation Probabilities: Explanation required

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand this question from khan's academy. It is to calculate expected value.

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/random-variables-topic/expected-value/e/expected-value-with-calculated-probabilities

The following is the question:

> Denis is currently unemployed and wants to become the manager of Roberto's Restaurant. To become a manager in Roberto's Restaurant, Denis first has to serve as a cook there. To become a cook in Roberto's Restaurant, he first has to serve as a waiter there.
>   Denis has a 60%, percent chance of being hired as a waiter. If he becomes a waiter, he has a 50%, percent chance of being promoted to cook. If he becomes a cook, he has a 40%, percent chance of being promoted to manager.
>   At Roberto's Restaurant, managers get paid \$25 per hour, cooks get paid \$15 per hour, and waiters get paid \$10 per hour. If Denis stays unemployed, he will make \$0 per hour.
>   What is the expected hourly payoff of Denis's plan to seek employment at Roberto's Restaurant?

I know the solution, but I am seeking an explanation for the same, as I am not able to understand that why the cases such as if dennis becomes waiter but not cook has been taken? Infact, for manager, the probability of waiter and cook has been multiplied.

Comment: I think the quoted question is terrible. First, it's horribly contrived: restaurants just don't work like that, so why use it as an example? Second, it's completely unclear. Even if restaurants did work like that, it's obvious that Denis would have to work for some period of time as a waiter before being promoted, and then for some period as a cook before being promoted again. Any real analysis would have to take that into account, whereas the question seems to want you to assume that he walks through the door and the owner immediately starts tossing coins to decide on promotions.

Answer (score 1):

He has a $40\%$ chance of remaining unemployed, and a $60\%$ chance of being hired on as a waiter.

He has a $30\%$ chance of remaining a waiter (half of his chances of being hired as a waiter) and $30\%$ chance of being promoted to cook.  This is another way of expressing that he has even odds of being promoted to cook, *given that* he was hired as a waiter.

He has a $30\% \cdot 60\% = 18\%$ chance of remaining a cook, and $30\% \cdot 40\% = 12\%$ chance of being promoted to manager.  This is another way of expressing that he has a $0.4$ chance of being promoted to manager, *given that* he achieved cook status.

This makes his expected hourly payoff

$$\$0 \cdot 0.4 + \$10 \cdot 0.3 + \$15 \cdot 0.18 + \$25 \cdot 0.12 = \$8.70.$$

Note that at each step along the way, the probabilities of all possibilities add to $1$:  $0.4 + 0.6$; $0.4 + 0.3 + 0.3$; $0.4 + 0.3 + 0.18 + 0.12.$